# How to get rid of "MaxBack Engine" for good?

Tags: macos, mac

I used to have a Maxtor Shared Storage II network drive; it broke down long ago already. (Later I tried to [recover some data](https://superuser.com/questions/108596/how-to-get-data-out-of-a-maxtor-shared-storage-ii-that-fails-to-boot) from it, and partially succeeded, but haven't yet fully documented it on that question.)

**Anyway**, I just noticed there are still some lingering bits remaining of the (thoroughly crappy) software that came with the Maxtor device: a **background process called "MaxBack Engine"**.

[image]

I googled around a bit and found something related but not very useful:

- http://www.straitmac.com/jforum/posts/list/600.page
- http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=725692

Under `/Applications` I found "Maxtor EasyManage.app" which I used to use for controlling the drive, and showed it some "`rm -rf`". Before deleting, I noted that the bundle *did* contain "MaxBack Engine.app" under Content/Resources.

But still, after reboot, the "MaxBack Engine" process is back. I did notice though that it only appears when logging in with my usual user account; with another account it wasn't launched.

So, dear Mac gurus, **what could I do about this pest**? I guess I could fall back to some Unix hackery and write a cronjob that kills any process with that name, but obviously it'd be nicer to be able to clean up from my computer everything left behind by Maxtor's piece of software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh well, it wasn't that difficult after all.

I looked under **System Prefs -> Accounts -> Login Items**, and "MaxBack Engine" was there on the list, along with the possibility to disable it from starting upon login.

[image]

The tooltip additionally told me the application is at:

```
/Library/Application Support/Maxtor/MaxBack Engine.app
```

So, I deleted ([permanently](https://superuser.com/questions/10676/permanently-deleting-files-on-mac-os)) the whole Maxtor directory (it contained another file called "MBHelperTool" along with "MaxBack Engine.app"), and verified (by reboot & login) that it indeed is gone for good now!

Comment: Yet another case of me basically using SU as a "rubber duck", but oh well :)

Answer (score 1):

While that was a pretty easy case, anytime you can't find a self-healing bit of software, this usually will:

http://khiltd.com/software/consultants_canary

Comment: Thanks, good to know about Consultant’s Canary. I just tried it out, and it seems like a really useful tool!

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find out how to remove it, chmod it 000.

Comment: In my case there was no problem deleting the culprit after I found it - thanks anyway!